# ionic: can't launch android emulator from terminal

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

I have configured ionic android developing environment. I can open my android project in Android studio 2.2.2 and launch the app in an emulator and it all works fine.

But if I go to my terminal and go to my ionic project. And build or emulate android like:

```
ionic build android
ionic emulate android
```

I get an error:

```
Error: /Users/alex_fimm_dev/Desktop/Projects/ionic/myApp2/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApk'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
      > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
         > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.
           Searched in the following locations:
               https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.pom
               https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.jar
           Required by:
               android:CordovaLib:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Again the project runs fine on Android Studio.

Not sure if I am missing some step or something, Started yesterday with ionic.

Here are some of my versions:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
Android 7.1.1 API 25
Android SDK Tools 25.2.4
Android Platform-Tools 25.0.3
Cordova 6.4.0
node 7.3.0
npm  4.0.5
os x yosemite 10.10.2
```

Comment: `ionic run android`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove platforms/android folder

```
ionic platform rm android
```

and add Android again:

```
ionic platform add android
```